# How to optimize the norm of the convolution of two images?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, optimization, signal-processing, convolution

I am trying to optimize this function:

[image: objective function]

where:

`p` is an NxN image.
`k` is an NxN image.
`tc` is an NxN image.
`*` is the convolution of image `k` and image `p`.
`grad()` is the gradient of the image.
`||·||_L1` is the L1 norm.
`||·||_L2` is the L2 norm.
`theta` is a constant.

I need to code this in MATLAB to solve in an iterative way. I need help solving for `p`.

---

I have followed [*this example*](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/49366-image-processing-minimizing-function-regularized-least-square-problem) to proceed with the minimization algorithm. However, I am not sure how to represent the `k ∗` convolution part and put it in the `H` vector. Perhaps, this is not the best way to do it.

I have already coded the looping part following the page 7 of [this paper](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2717307).

Comment: What have you coded so far?

Comment: I have followed this example to proceed with the minimization algorithm. However, I am not sure how to represent the k* convolution part and put it in the H vector. Perhaps, this is not the best way to do it.           
          https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/49366-image-processing-minimizing-function-regularized-least-square-problem

Comment: The looping part I have already coded following page 7 of this paper     https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2717307

Comment: Convolution is a linear operator and as such has a matrix representation. The gradient of ||Ax-b|| is well known.

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 it is not a product. ||A*x-b|| where * is convolution. I am applying Young's inequality to see where it gets me, but I need help coding it. Perhaps any references where I can find that example.

Comment: @oxj What I mean is the convolution of two vectors, a*b, is equal to a matrix-vector product, Ab, where the rows of A are shifted copies of the vector a. You can use this to derive the gradient of the 2-norm.

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 so I wouldn't use ||k*p|| = |k||_L1 ||p||_L2 ?

Comment: @oxj The convolution of k and p is equal to the product of their one-norm and two-norm? I don't believe that. A simple counter example is any two vectors with non-overlapping frequency spectrums.

Comment: @oxj I briefly browsed the paper you linked. In section 6 they somewhat describe how they solved the problem. Have you tried reading the papers they reference?

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 young's inequality states ||k*p|| < = |k||_L1 ||p||_L2 , found this in literature and the references. I will look more into it. Thank you